# Call function with arguments without parenthesis in C?

Tags: c, function

When a function does not have any argument, it is possible to call it without parenthesis by `define` as

```
#define test test()
```

Is it possible to call a function with argument without paranthesis? Something like

```
#define test test(char *arg)

test "argument 1";
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @luiscubal mostly, out of curiosity (not necessity). I want to know how much `C` is flexible to change it towards coding in high-level languages.

Comment: What would the rules for function precedence be: Is `foo x + bar y` `foo(x) + bar(y)` or `foo(x + bar(y))`? Either way, I'm 99% sure there's no way to do this in plain C.

Comment: probably not in C, but in C++ one can define `test` as an `std::stringstream() << ` where the immediately following string argument will be sent to its `operator <<`.

Comment: There's a big difference between developing a high-level language in C and trying to turn C into a high-level language.  Disguised C will still be C with all of its pitfalls, and rearranging the function call construct to mimic the style used by some other language won't change that.  If you need a high-level language, use a high-level language.

Comment: C + preprocessor macros != a high-level language. It's the combination of a low-level systems language and a low-level text processing language, with all the problems of both.

Comment: @Useless:  And all this time I thought C was just a convenient shorthand for all of that assembly I used to write.  :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not going to be possible in C the way you have it. §6.5.2 of the standard (C99) describes postfix expressions, and has no syntax like that. Function calls are (§6.5.2.2):

> A postfix expression followed by parentheses `()` containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of expressions is a function call. The postfix expression denotes the called function. The list of expressions specifies the arguments to the function.

Parens are not optional, and they need to wrap all the arguments so you need either a function-like macro (which requires parens at the "call" site) or two separate things (one to insert the starting paren, one to insert the closing one).

You could do:

```
#define test puts(
#define end  );
#define int_proc int
#define proc_body {
#define proc_end  }
#define no_args (void)
#include <stdio.h>

int_proc main no_args
proc_body
  test "hello" end
proc_end
```

But... really?

C++ offers more possibilities with operator overloading in particular. You might want to look into that if you want to "customize" some syntax.

Here's a horrible example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void operator=(char const* str)
    {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
};
Foo global_foo;

#define test global_foo =

int main()
{
    test "hello";
}
```

Note that there are sane approaches that you might find attractive, e.g. Qt's `qDebug` utility class. Schematically, it goes like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct debug {
    debug() {}
    ~debug()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    debug const& operator<<(char const* msg) const
    {
        std::cout << msg << " ";
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The usual way of using it would be:

```
debug() << "this" << "works";
```

If you add a constructor that takes `char const*`:

```
debug(char const*msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << " ";
}
```

Then you can use cast notation and write:

```
(debug) "Hello";
```

Which is pretty close to what you had (and is macroable).

Then you can get fancy with all the other operators (`operator,` would be a prime candidate), but precedence rules might ruin the fun a bit.

Comment: +1: Horrible is in the eye of beholder. See [googletest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer) : `ASSERT_EQ(expected, actual) << "message to show if fails";`

Comment: @rwong: That statement at least resembles a valid C++ statement. `test "hello";` does not and anything that makes it legal is for that reason horrible. What googletest does is not IMHO.