# C functions without return type and parentheses?

Tags: c, syntax

I've came across a piece of C code (allegedly - the file has .c suffix).

It has a bunch of functions defined like so:

```
do_stuff
{
    // some stuff
}

do_other_stuff
{
   // some more stuff
}
```

There is no `#define do_stuff do_stuff()` in the code, neither an `#include` of any external file.

The code is run on some SDS relay device.

What is that? From the surrounding code and the way they are called, I assume they have `void` return type and no arguments, but what's up with the syntax?

Is this a thing in C, or some special C dialect?

Comment: Doesn't look valid code at all. Can't you show something that will compile?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `do_stuff() { }`? `do_stuff { }` has never been valid C code.

Comment: You cannot have function without `()` even in K&R style. Maybe `do_stuff` etc. are macros?

Comment: Well I suppose it might be something _based on_ C rather than real C, but the file is `*.c`... and no, there are no arguments at all. Also, there are no includes at all, but some functions are still used that apparently came from somewhere else. The rest is, however, looking very much like C.

Comment: You are asking us to work out what this is, but only revealing small fragments of information. It could be anything. I bet the real code doesn't even say "do_stuff". It's very hard to know what you are really asking. Why can't you show something that will compile? Or at least why can't you show the real code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The names are different, but there is no include at all in the file and also no macro definitions. So I assumed it is some strange way of writing C.

Comment: There's all sorts of information that you have, that we don't. Why are you concealing information from us? Where did you get the file from? Did you ask whoever you got it from? Did you steal it which is why you won't reveal any information? Or can you tell us where it came from? Why are we bothering to help you at all?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan got it from a colleague who asked me to help finding a bug in it. It's said to work, but unfortunately I don't have a makefile that comes with it, nor the rest of the project (if there is any), so I don't know what I'm really dealing with. I was told it is C, and got this weird file. With C suffix. That's really all I know.

Comment: Are you supposed to compile it as well, or is that done "elsewhere"? It *might* be a simple script language, by the way.

Comment: And you decided to ask us rather than your colleague?!?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought it is just some new way of writing methods that I didn't know, so I asked, yes. Didn't expect such strong reactions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While functions are allowed to omit the return type (defaults to `int`), they're not allowed to omit empty parentheses. Either it's a superset of C, or (more likely) they're actually macro definitions. Otherwise, it's not valid C.

Comment: my crystal ball says it's a macro too. oh well, it's the same thing again and again. guys, please post complete code. in this case, look up the definition of `do_stuff`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath There is no #define's other than some constants. I'm not sure where the macros would be defined if they were indeed macros, for there is also no #include's. I'll try to get more of the code (if there is more), maybe it will reveal some secrets.

Comment: @MightyPork: does it compile? :)

Comment: @MightyPork Please post the real code instead of asking people to speculate on fake code.

Comment: @ouah I cannot do that, but there is really nothing more that would help you, I think. There is a couple of #DEFINE's for some constants, a `main {}`, some functions (using goto, label, if's etc). One strange thing is that variables are defined as `var`.

Comment: @MightyPork then either there's some other preprocessing going on, or (like I said) it's a superset of C, because `var` is certainly not a C keyword.

Comment: Yeah looks that way. Something based on C but not C.

Comment: Okay turns out it was SDS-C, some very limited proprietary C-based language.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not you case but I came upon this question

[Call function with arguments without parenthesis in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348620/call-function-with-arguments-without-parenthesis-in-c)

Maybe it is related to the code you have. Either way it is an example of that kind of syntax in `C`.