# Problem Deleting Node of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, reference, binary-search-tree

I am implementing a binary search tree in C ++, but the code has an error, when deleting a node with 2 children the resulting tree is not well connected, the method to delete a node with 0 or 1 child works well. This code is based in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31698320/11053027 .

**Edit:**
For example if a add the values in this order: 17, 12, 25, and then I try delete 17 that is the root, it is deleted, so when I try to show all the elements are: 12, 25, with 25 as root.
But if now I try to delete 12 it is not deleted, the problem is caused when I first deleted 17. No error message is shown.

Can you help me please. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
    Node<E> *getSuccesor(Node<E> &node) const {
       auto *Succesor = node.right;
       while (Succesor != nullptr) {
          if (Succesor->left == nullptr) return Succesor;
          Succesor = Succesor->left;
       }
       return Succesor;
    }

    void remove(Node<E> &node) {
       if (&node == nullptr) return;
       int nChildren = numChildren(node);
       Node<E> *child;

       if (nChildren == 2) {
        child = getSuccesor(node);
        remove(*child);
        child->parent = node.parent;
        child->left = node.left;
        child->right = node.right;
        if (&node == root)
            root = child;
        else {
            if (&node == node.parent->right)
                node.parent->right = child;
            else node.parent->left = child;
        }
    } else {
        child = (node.left != nullptr ? node.left : node.right);

        if (child != nullptr)
            child->parent = node.parent;

        if (&node == root)
            root = child;
        else {
            if (&node == node.parent->left)
                node.parent->left = child;
            else node.parent->right = child;
        }
    }
    Size--;
 }
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? Care to elaborate in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348620/call-function-with-arguments-without-parenthesis-in-c) please. Also make your code a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain, since you haven't given us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I think the problem is here:

```
if (nChildren == 2) {
  child = getSuccesor(node);
  remove(*child);
  child->parent = node.parent;
  child->left = node.left;
  child->right = node.right;
```

So now `child` knows its children. But they don't know that `child` is now their parent. Their `parent` pointers still point to the defunct node (in this case, '17'), which messes up the logic in the next removal.

After those lines, add these:

```
if(child->left)
  child->left->parent = child;
if(child->right)
  child->right->parent = child;
```

**EDIT:** The same bug is also in the other branch of the if-else conditional, but I'm sure you can see how to fix it there too.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, just one last question, to completely remove that node at the end of the function do I have to do: delete node.element; ? And do nothing with node.left, node.right and node.parent, right?

Comment: @Alexander: [I don't know what `element` is, and I don't know how you constructed the nodes in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but yes, you must dispose of that node somehow.